# CMS , не подключается контролер по URL пути admin/login из окружения admin

Tags: php, cms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть в CMS два окружения admin (темплейты) и cms (движок) в обоих окружениях есть контроллеры и роуты, так вот оба окружения работают, но URL пути из окружения cms (**DIR**) работают, а из окружения admin нет. 
Ошибок в Браузере нет, потому что, роуты и методы подтягиваются с cms окружения, а должны с admin...
Где искать проблемму, nginx?

Comment: Ошибок в браузере нет наверное потому что их вывод отключен, попробуйте включить? И вы уверены что у вас подгружается admin а не cms но уже с контроллером admin и экшеном login?

Comment: Что вообще за CMS(фреймворк я думаю) вы используете?

Comment: .../admin окружение работает и контролеры тоже , всё подключается, но только переход по url .../admin/login и усё , подтягивает контролеры из окружения cms (ErrоrController 'ошибка 404', такой же контроллер и в окружениии admin есть, но его не подтягивает)...

Comment: Что за CMS(фреймворк) стоит? Могу предложить для начала переименовать контроллер login в админ окружении например на ad_login и попробовать перейти по admin/ad_login и посмотреть что он скажет

Comment: фрейм писал человек, но использовал апач, и решал эту проблемму через .htaccess файл, который он разместил в обоих окружениях, а я на жинксе...пытался регулярки конвертировать  и в кофиг жинкса ложить, но не решил проблемму

Comment: А другие контроллеры тоже совпадают названиями в двух окружениях?

Comment: покажите конфиг apache (как изначально разработчики делали) и конфиг nginx (то что вы сделали). я думаю у вас 2 точки входа типа index.php

Comment: я понимаю, что тяжело без исходников понимать в чём трабла, но спс за интерес...) всё выложу с конкретикой по-красоте

Comment: Не вижу конфигов апача и nginx

Comment: не силён в серверной части. права на все папки и файлы сделал. вообщем искал решение и старался, но пока безуспешно. хотелось бы подойти к вопросу конструктивно и не искать траблу везде. сузить круг поиска и идти последовательно. думаю, что трабла в жинксе или логике кодаю  код перепроверял, там всё чётко, ошибок не выдаёт, а вот логика походу не та.

Comment: @Total Pusher
вот ссыль на cms
[ссылка]https://github.com/Aleksus81/cms.git

Comment: `define('ENV', 'Admin');` выполняется? Поставьте `var_dump(ENV);` после этого и выхлоп сюда

Comment: @Total Pusher 
/admin/ - выводит string(3) "ENV"
/admin/login - всё равно цепляет контроллер из cms окружения

Comment: require_once __DIR__ . '/../' . strtolower(ENV) . '/Route.php';
$controller = '\\' . ENV . '\\Controller\\' . $class;
ENV - константа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением дополнительного location /admin/login  в конфиг nginx и добавления роута в контролер на этот location /admin/login

Comment: Вот показали бы конфиги, как я просил, проблема решилась быстрее.

Comment: Все скрины были выложенны в начале